# how to get the Nth column of array of arrays in python

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

I have array names y

and y.shape gives

```
y.shape
Out[6]: (9976, 158)
```

the value of y is

```
y
Out[3]: 
array([[0, 0, 1, ..., 0, 0, 0],
       [0, 0, 1, ..., 0, 0, 0],
       [0, 0, 0, ..., 0, 0, 0],
       ...,
       [0, 0, 0, ..., 0, 0, 0],
       [0, 0, 0, ..., 0, 0, 0],
       [1, 0, 0, ..., 0, 0, 0]])
```

I want to get the Nth column of each array

[image]

I tried y[N] but that gave the Nth row

so

```
y[0]
Out[4]: 
array([0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0,
       0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0,
       0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0,
       0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0,
       0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0,
       0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0,
       0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 1, 0,
       0, 0, 0, 0])
```

how can I do that?

Comment: Are you using numpy?

Comment: i can use any libraru

Comment: Numpy nth column of 2d array: `y[:, n]`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use 2D slicing: `y[:, n]`

`:` -> all values in the first dimension (rows)

`n` -> just the nth column